# Magento 2 less workflow suggestions

Tags: less, magento2

I'm having a hard time locating specific style rules in less, what is the ideal workflow for quickly finding and modifying the rules and structure of the default less files?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111446/how-to-solve-css-validation-using-total-validator-tool-in-magento-2/111451#111451

Comment: I hope above link is useful for you @user3621758

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Magento Documentation is pretty helpful here - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

Source maps are probably the best LESS debugging tool.

For client side compilation configure options in `lib/web/less/config.less.js`. 
The option you want is:

> dumpLineNumbers
>
> Type: String Options: ''| 'comments'|'mediaquery'|'all' Default: ''
>
> When set, this adds source line information to the output css file. This helps you debug where a particular rule came from.
>   - http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser

If you want server side compilation, you can use grunt which is built in to Magento 2. Checkout the `dev/tools/grunt/configs/less.js` file, it shows

```
var lessOptions = {
options: {
    sourceMap: true,
    strictImports: false,
    sourceMapRootpath: '/',
    dumpLineNumbers: false, // use 'comments' instead false to output 
    ...
```

The documentation will step you through using Grunt, or setting up client side less compilation.